# In Vimperator how to configure the number of lines of proposal when using the command ":history" ?

Tags: firefox, vimperator

I'm using Vimperator.

I'd like to configure the number of lines that are display by Vimperator ,as proposals, when I'm looking up in history with the command

```
:history
```

for the moment my page is completely covered with proposals.

in my vimperatorrc i configured

```
previewheight=20
```

in order to have 20 propositions when I'm using completion on the command line but this is working with open completion not with :history.

**My Question:**

how can i set the numbers of lines I'd like to have displayed as proposals when I type the command  ?

```
:history
```

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the -max flag, for example:

```
:history -max=20
```

Comment: is it possible to add a replacement for the default command in vimperatorrc ?  if yes how ?

Comment: @toshi Ask another question and paste the link here

Comment: @toshi for the record, I'm not sure there is but you always just create a new command or mapping and use that

Comment: ":history"  will show the list limited by the value configured.
":ls"  will show all the buffers without limit.